# cURL error 60 in Symfonycasts tutorial

Tags: windows, php, ssl, curl

In Symfonycasts "API Platform: Serious RESTful APIs" [Chapter 6](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform/hydra) there is the cURL command `curl -X GET "https://localhost:8000/api" -H "accept: application/ld+json"`. Running this command (with adding  `-v`) on Windows results in

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

In a Linux system (Ubuntu 20.04), with an existing Symfony project identical to that used in Windows above, the same command yields the expected `{"@context":"\/api\/contexts\/Entrypoint","@id":"\/api","@type":"Entrypoint","nonprofit":"\/api\/nonprofits"}`

In both cases the commands `symfony server:start -d` and `symfony server:ca:install` had been run.

What I need to know, I think, is how to add a certificate in Windows that will satisfy cURL's concern "...curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server..."

Answer (score 0):

Without fully understanding why, the command to use in Windows is:

`curl -k "https://localhost:8000/api" -H "accept: application/ld+json"`